# Java: Getting a substring from a string ending before a particular character

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee, substring, longest-substring

I have a String

`Millett Angle-Loc Weaver Extension 1 inch Rings, Black, Medium, Front/Rear Exte`

I would like to extract  `"Millett Angle-Loc Weaver Extension 1 inch Rings, Black, Medium, Front/Rear"`
from this `String`, ie, the substring before the last `" "`(space/blank) (*or first from right*).

Could someone please provide some help?

Comment: Whats the desired output? It looks same as input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input String is `str`, try this. It should do it.

```
int i = str.lastIndexOf(' ');
String str1 = i >= 0 ? str.substring(0, i) : "";
String str2 = str.substring(i + 1);
System.out.println(str1);   
System.out.println(str2);
```

See also:
[String.lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

```
final String str = "Millett Angle-Loc Weaver Extension 1 inch Rings, Black, Medium, Front/Rear Exte";

System.out.printf("%s\n", str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(' ')));
```

This prints:

`Millett Angle-Loc Weaver Extension 1 inch Rings, Black, Medium, Front/Rear`

Comment: @yogesh9239 You are welcome! You can mark an answer as accepted if it helped and satisfied you.